# Don't deserialize not passed values

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

Question regarding PHP serializer: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

I have request DTO which used for PATCH requests.

```
<?php

class RequestDTO
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    private ?string $publicId = null;

    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    private ?string $title = null;
```

if request contains only 1 field as an e.g. other field receives null value.

e.g. request

```
{
    "publicId": "1a-d4-5t6"
}
```

result will be:

```
-publicId: "1a-d4-5t6"
-title: null
```

But I don't want to set `title` to null in this case as title value is not present in request. How to configure JMS serializer to not deserialize fields when they are not passed?

Comment: Won’t `title` be null regardless of the deserialization process since that is the default value?

Comment: @ChrisHaas good catch! That's the thing.

Comment: @darjus how did you solve that? In case you use a DTO to update an entity, if the title is not present then you will override the title of the entity to null!